# termination of finite lists

Tags: haskell, terminate

```
pp :: [a] -> [a]
pp list = case list of
    [] -> []
    (x: _) -> x : (qq list)


qq :: [a] -> [a]
qq list = case list of
    [] -> []
    (x: xs) -> (pp xs) ++ [x]
```

Does the function pp terminate for finite lists? If so: how often are the functions pp and qq called in total if pp is called with a list of n elements? If pp does not terminate for finite lists, then why not.

I think the function pp will terminate, if pp is called with a list of n elements, pp and q will call 2n in total.

Comment: Smells like homework... Did you try solving it yourself?

Comment: Take a pen and paper and work through it with the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and  then you can tell us whether it terminates and a reasonable guess for the complexity

Answer (score 1):

One way to prove that a recursive calculation will terminate if the size of its input is (a) finite and (b) decreasing.

Let's look at `pp`

```
pp :: [a] -> [a]
pp list = case list of
    [] -> []
    (x: _) -> x : (qq list)
```

The last line returns `x:qq list`, but the input was `list`, so it calls `qq` with the same length list.

Let's see what `qq` does:

```
qq :: [a] -> [a]
qq list = case list of
    [] -> []
    (x: xs) -> (pp xs) ++ [x]
```

Here, we call `pp xs`, where we've matched `list` with the pattern `x:xs`. This means `x` is the head (first element) and `xs` is the tail (rest-of-list), so `xs` is one element shorter than the input, `list`.

This means that the length of the input decreases by one every time we call `qq` and doesn't decrease when we call `pp`. Hence you're right that there are a total number of 2n calls, which is of course finite, so the calculation terminates.